# How to do regression discontinuity design analysis in python

Tags: python, statistics

In Stata and R, there are well-established packages for estimating regression discontinuity design models:

- https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.09511.pdf
- https://www.stata.com/meeting/columbus15/abstracts/materials/columbus15_cattaneo.pdf
- https://www.econometrics-with-r.org/13-4-quasi-experiments.html#regression-discontinuity-estimators
- https://rpubs.com/phle/r_tutorial_regression_discontinuity_design

I could not a full-featured package with associated tutorial for estimating RDD models in Python.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could check the Python version of rdrobust package
[rdrobust](https://pypi.org/project/rdrobust/)